# Google Cloud Platform Firebase Installations Api shows only errors

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform

I have an Android App using

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.2.2'
```

In my Google Cloud Platform project I have an Api Key which is not restricted for APIs, but is restricted to Android Application using the package name and the SHA-1 fingerprint (managed by Google Play Console).

I got an email alert saying Firebase services for your application are malfunctioning due to Application restrictions, if I go to the Firebase Installations API (which is enabled) I can see an alarming amount of errors for "CreateInstallation".

This only happens in my Prod environment, and google-services.json is correctly setup. Am I wrong in restricting to Android Apps? Or could something else be happening?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: It is better contact to [firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact) to review your case closer

Comment: Thanks, will try there